# Search form with PDO

Tags: php, search, pdo

**The below code now works but how can I make it so if no results are found it echos a message instead of blank.**

I think I've managed to create a search query for my database. Its only a very basic search but it doesn't seem to work for some reason. Any advice would be appreciated im still new to pdo (very new! be kind!).

Also no user submitted data is inserted into the database so I think i can rule out xss assuming its SQL inject free? Which from what I understand PDO is? plus im using a stand alone DB user with no write access.

Have replace data with xxx for security

file is called search.php

*updated to reflect changes suggested
*2nd update to reflect help provided
*3rd update

```
   <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="search.php">
  <table width="599" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Keyword
      <input name="var1" type="text" id="var1">
      <input type="submit" value="Search"></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<?php
$nameofdb = 'xxxxxx';
$dbusername = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$dbpassword = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';



// Connect to MySQL via PDO
try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$nameofdb;host=localhost", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$var1 = str_replace(array('%','_'),'',$_POST['var1']);
if (!$var1)
{
    exit('Invalid form value: '.$var1);
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM xxxxx WHERE xxxxxx LIKE :search OR xxxxx LIKE :search";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':search', '%' . $var1 . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");


 $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach( $result as $row ) {
    echo $row["id"];
    echo $row["title"];
}




?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that, even though you're using prepared statements, I can still have your script return the entire DB by filling in nothing, `_` or `%` in the form (MySQL wildcards). you'd do well in checking user input regardless of using prepared statements or not

Comment: Hi thanks, how do I do this? I used to use mysqli_real_escape_string but im lost int PDO world!

Comment: simply check: `$var1 = str_replace(array('%','_'),'',$_POST['var1']); if (!$var){ exit('Invalid form value: '.$var1);}`

Comment: Have I added this in the correct place? Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: Hi Elias
I now have this script working with 
$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
but not
$var1 = str_replace(array('%','_'),'',$_POST['var1']); if (!$var){ exit('Invalid form value: '.$var1);}

does this replace $var1 = $_POST['var1']; or do i add it above it/below?

Comment: you'll just have to replace the regular assignment (`$var1 = $_POST['var1'];` with `$var1 = str_replace(array('%','_'),'',$_POST['var1']);` the `if` statement after that will evaluate to true (and exit, without performing the query) when the user entered only wildcards, or 0

Comment: everything comes up as "Invalid form value:searchterm"

Comment: have updated the code above to reflect your changes. Thanks for your help with this. Once I get your bit working with the code I think im SQL_inject free

Comment: because you have `!$var` but is has to be `!$var1`

Comment: WAHEY! it works! ok so 2 final questions.
1) is this script SQL_inject free then?
2) how to I reward users on here with points etc?

Comment: @user1657967: Perry's right, I edited your post. Note that the code, as it now stands will always issue `invalid form value:` when the client views the form for the first time, as the PHP code is embedded in the HTML page

Comment: brill, so just to confirm its inject free (im paranoid about this!) also ive accepted perry but how do i reward @elias for the help on here?

Comment: dam,  when I enter a space it echos the entire database?
**false alarm hadn't uploaded new file**

Comment: @user1657967: if that's the case, either change the array in the `str_replace()`, and add a `' '` value (not recommended), or wrap the entire `str_replace` expression in a `trim` call: `$var1 = trim(str_replace(array(),'',$_POST));`

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again but how would I echo the results e.g. echo just the ID at the end instead of all the details?
e.g. usually id do echo $row['id']; but his doesn't seem to work

Comment: think ive fixed it with $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach( $result as $row ) {
    echo $row["id"];
 echo $row["title"];
}

Comment: The above code now works but how can I make it so if no results are found it echos a message instead of blank.

Comment: @user1657967 see my update 4 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the form. the method is `GET` but in your php you expect `$_POST`

So this line:

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="get" action="search.php">
```

should be:

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="search.php">
```

**UPDATE**

Change your code to this:

```
// Connect to MySQL via PDO
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$nameofdb;host=localhost", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$var1 = $_POST['var1'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM xxxxx WHERE xxxx LIKE :search OR xxxxx LIKE :search";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':search', '%' . $var1 . '%',);
$stmt->execute();
```

To check if there are no line and give a message you can do it like this:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
if ($result) { 
    foreach( $result as $row ) {
        echo $row["id"];
        echo $row["title"];
    }
} else {
    echo 'There is nothing to show';
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. tried
$var1 = $_GET['var1'];
and
also tried changing 
method="post"
but lo luck. any other ideas?
Thanks again

Comment: have update the code above to reflex changes but sadly not working

Comment: again thanks for your help with this. I new get the "Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set" message on my page but when I search no results show up.

Comment: sweet thanks, If i use the 
$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
and the other changes you suggested it works :)
just got the $var1 = str_replace(array('%','_'),'',$_POST['var1']); if (!$var){ exit('Invalid form value: '.$var1);}
 issue above now to fix

Comment: It actually should be GET method, not POST

Comment: @YourCommonSense and why should it be a GET?

Comment: Because internet standards state it

Answer (score -1):

i wrote this method and use in every project i working on it . try it :)

```
public function searchForQueryString($queryString)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `xxxx` WHERE (`xxxxxxx` like :queryString or `xxxxx` like :queryString) ";

    $sth = $this->prepare($query);
    $queryString = '%' . $queryString . '%';
    $sth->bindParam('queryString', $queryString, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $sth->execute();

    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if(empty($result) or $result == false)
       return array();
    else
        return $result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I modified Amir's code and it works:

```
protected $pdo;

public function __construct($pdo)
{
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
}

public function selectSearch($table, $search)

{
    $statement = $this->pdo->prepare("select * from {$table} WHERE post_tags LIKE '%$search%'");

    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    if(empty($result) or $result == false){
        echo "<h1> No Result</h1>";
        return array();
    } else{
        return $result;
  }}


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $search = $_POST['search'];

            $data = $query->selectSearch('posts', $search);
        }
```

Comment: Congratulations, you just added to Amir's code code a first class **SQL INJECTION**