# Searching MySQL database

Tags: php, search, pdo, mysqli

I'm making a movie website and you can search through the database to find a wanted title but I have a problem...
How to search a database with PDO? I have something like this:

```
$search=$_GET['search'];
$search='%'.$search.'%';
$db = new mysqli($DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpassword, $DBdatabase);
$sql="SELECT id, title, year, front_image, description FROM a358_filmovi WHERE title LIKE ?";
$sl=$db->prepare($sql);
$sl->bind_param('s',$search);
$sl->execute();
$sl->bind_result($id, $title, $year, $front_image, $description);
while($sl->fetch()){
?>
    DATA OUTPUT
<?php
}
```

And the problem is that I have record *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 1* and if I search for Harry **Potter** it will display that movie as a result but if I search for Harry **potter**, it won't display anything (blank result).

That's just an example movie, it's not working for any movie from the database.

How can I edit this code to match every result from search input, uppercase or lowercase?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083455/mysql-like-case-sensitive

Comment: @Devon Well isn't 's' standing there for 'string', 'i' for 'integer' etc.?

Comment: My fault, I misunderstood what you were after.

Comment: Change your column encoding to utf_general_ci

Comment: Your code isn't PDO. Or, are you asking how to do it with PDO?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, I'm asking that...

Comment: One thing to point out is this really won't be very efficient under any sort of load with any sort of large data set.  You'll be doing a full table scan each query.  You might be better off looking at actual full text search engines that can do this sort of thing incredibly fast.  Though, as a learning exercise this is of course perfectly fine.

Comment: @Vlada903, you're using mysqli not PDO.  As suggested, any _ci encoding will be case insensitive.

Comment: SQL is SQL, no matter how you slice it. The methods/APIs used will all use the same basic syntax, whether it be mysql, mysqli, PDO, other. All that changes really is how you bind and fetch the data.

Comment: Having looked over to the right under "Related", found this Q&A on SO that will get you started http://stackoverflow.com/q/17674369/

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok, but what's the fastest way to search through the database to find title with MySQLi?

Comment: Fastest way? I'd say try and limit your search to specific columns. Am sure there are other methods, but as far as I know (so far), would be one way of avoiding having to go through multiple columns.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Actually, my search is limited only to the 'title' column so that's not a problem.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to do this in PDO, it is fairly similar.  You can bind the param in the execute() function to avoid using bindParam() also.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$sql="SELECT id, title, year, front_image, description FROM a358_filmovi WHERE title LIKE ?";
$sl=$db->prepare($sql);
$sl->execute(array('%'.$_GET['search'].'%');
```

Should work.

Instead of using SQL or PHP to do a case insensitive search, your best to change the column encoding to _ci (ci stands for case insensitive) in the schema.

Comment: Won't this still be case-sensitive?

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: I've updated it specifying more about PDO and column encoding.

Comment: @Devon Encoding changed and now it works either with mysqli or pdo but what if I search for 'harry hallows'? It will return blank result although I have a record with a title 'Harry Potter....Hallows: Part 1'. How to find these two word if they are not one next to other?

Comment: @Vlada903 Good question.  I'm not sure how you would do that with SQL, I'm sure there is a way, especially with full text.  With PHP, I could think of splitting the words with `explode(' ')` and adding a `LIKE %word% AND` for every word.

Comment: @Vlada903 - The `LIKE` operator simply doesn't allow fuzzy searching like this.  You need to be using a full text search engine.  This is why they were invented.